# Keep alive in node.js using http for POST

Tags: node.js, http, post, keep-alive

I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I haven't figured it out yet. In Python, we have a good library for http requests, `requests`. Now it's pretty simple to use and I made a simple program to just test the concept:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('website.com',data={login details here})
r = s.post('website.com/something',data={other details})
```

This works great and does everything I want, but unfortunately it isn't in the language I was developing the application I wanted it for in the first place.

Now, of course a simple POST request isn't too difficult in node.js, but it's a little harder and I can't figure out how to `keep-alive` for the second connection. Using the below code, I can get one connection:

```
var options {
  options here, just know that I sent the keep-alive header
}
var req = http.request(options, function (res){
  console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (body) {
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
  });
 });
 req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
 });
 req.write();
 req.end();
}
```

Ok, so this is working fine, it's just I don't exactly know what to use to keep-alive and send a second request. I think I should use a `socket` but I don't exactly understand the docs, as they are extremely confusing to me. While searching through the internet, I couldn't seem to find anyone using POST keep-alive connections or really any connection twice. I really would appreciate an example of two different options/data on one `keep-alive` connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `http` core module, you should use `agent` to set `keep-alive`.

```
var myAgent = new http.Agent({
  keepAlive: true,
  maxSockets: 1,
  keepAliveMsecs: 3000
})
```

then use `request` module and set this as agent property of option, like bellow snippet

```
let url = require('url');
let request = require('request');

request.post({url:'http://website.com/something', agent: myAgent , form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,res,body){
    if(res.statusCode !== 200){
        console.log('err');
    } else {
        //set header cookie from response and send second request
    }
})
```

for setting second request cookie header from response car read [this](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2015/09/06/how-to-get-cookies-from-node-js-http-response/)

Comment: Stupid question, I know, but how exactly do I connect that to the requests?

Comment: Thanks! I’m not at my computer atm so I can’t implement it, but I’ll come back tomorrow and mark as answer.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I did wrong, but I basically just took the request and that twice and included this: https://gist.github.com/gsquaredxc/df4ebd8a452028d8bfa5636e7f4ae298 I have a Wireshark analysis of the packets and can't see what's wrong, but I know both packets are being sent with the correct info to the correct location.

Comment: Note that when you use `Session()` in python, cookies will be stored and send in next requests automatically, but in this case, you should set cookies to second request from response of first request.

Comment: There's no need to use an additional library, you simply set the agent in the core http request options.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use an additional library such as request.

Instead, instantiate a new http.agent object like so...

```
const keepAliveAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
```

And then include it in your http request options object like so...

```
const requestOptions = {
  agent: keepAliveAgent,
  headers: {
    Connection: 'keep-alive'
  }
  // the rest of your options...
}

const request = https.request(requestOptions, (response) => {
  // handle response here
});

request.write("your request body here"); // if you need to POST/PUT data
request.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP keep-alive is on by default in [modular AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/http-keep-alive-is-on-by-default-in-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) in AWS SDK for [JavaScript v3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/)

Answer (score 0):

For [Node.js v19](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v19-release-announce/#http-s-1-1-keepalive-by-default) or higher, the `keepAlive` option is set to true by default. So all the outgoing HTTP(s) will automatically use it.